# DialogFragment in Tabbed Activity wont show

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, tabs

The Fragment is part of a Tabbed Activity. I was able to succesfully modify the Tabbed Activity template of Android Studio 2.1.2. Now I have changed it to the point where all the Fragments inside it have a FAB of their own. When Floating Action Button is clicked it is supposed to show a dialog. I have created a DialogFragment following the instruction from the official docs. The FAB uses setOnClickListener to refer to the method in the java file. I can't use

```
newEdQua.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "createNewEdQua")
```

to show the dialog. it says it cannot resolve it

I also noticed that it won't load the ListView with the content of the Stinrg Array.

In summary I want to show a dialog from a Fragment(thats part of Tabbed Activity).

I have tried to clean and rebuild, sync gradle files with project. I dont want to mess with IDE configuration files. At least not now cause I'm far into a very important project(so suppressing warnings is not an option).

This is my code. It includes only areas with problem.

Dialog Fragment (to be shown):

```
public class createNewEdQua extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle saveSavedInstanceState){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setTitle(R.string.createnewEdQua);

    builder.setMessage("New Qualification HERE!!");

    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}
}
```

Fragment (placed as tab in Tabbed Activity):

```
public class edSET_Dashboard_Teachers extends Fragment {

FragmentManager fm;

//neInstance() method return reference to fragment
public static edSET_Dashboard_Teachers newInstance(){
    edSET_Dashboard_Teachers fragment = new edSET_Dashboard_Teachers();
    return fragment;
}


public edSET_Dashboard_Teachers() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//following code is in public View onCreateView() method
    String[] edqua={"Conten Here","Contend Here","Content Here"};

//had to use this cause findViewById() method was not working as it should
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edset__dashboard__teachers, container, false);


    ArrayAdapter<String> listOfEdqua2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.list_item_edqua, edqua);//i tried using this as the context but error

    ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.edu_info);
    listView.setAdapter(listOfEdqua2);


//had to use setOnClickListener cause android:onClick in xml does not work with Fragments ive learned
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab_edset);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DialogFragment newEdQua = new createNewEdQua();
            newEdQua.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "createNewEdQua");

            //addEdQua(view);
        }
    });


    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edset__dashboard__teachers, container, false);

}

//the method to show the dialog
/*
public void addEdQua(View view){

}*/

}
```

When I run it on a real device while connected to my computer, and I tap the FAB nothing at all happens, no crash no error nothing.

Comment: newEdQua.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "createNewEdQua") 
 do you call this inside a fragment ?

Comment: @Hala.m yes I have tried that inside the Fragment

Comment: this gives a compilaion error so did you try newEdQua.show( getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "createNewEdQua") ?

Comment: instead i used newEdQua.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "createNewEdQua") . I cant use getSupportFragmentManager. it displays no errors in the IDE. But when I test it on my device nothing at all happens , the dialog does not come up, no errors, nothing

Comment: kindly take a look at my edited post. Do you have any ideas why the ListView isnt showing the items from the ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edset__dashboard__teachers, container, false);
```

should be

```
return view;//it already inflates the Fragment layout
```

you are reinflating new view

Comment: I have included super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState); Also I corrected a small mistake in my code, it was 'Bundle saveSavedInstanceState' instead of 'Bundle savedInstanceState' in the DialogFragment onCreateDialog(). Your code is different from mine and changing it will affect everything else. Let me post my code to show you how I am implemeting the Fragments in the Tabbed Activity.

Comment: can you put a toast inside the fab on click to make sure it is fired?

Comment: It cant even show the toast. What could be wrong? Have you seen my full Fragment code?

Comment: check the new answer how did that go past us?

Comment: so I should just use return view; instead?

Comment: you are right that was the problem,it was even affecting the ArrayAdapter from showing up. Now the ArrayAdapter works and the FAB works to.. Would it be possible to team up on Android projects? just thought I should ask. I will mark your answer. I also edited your answer so it can be clear to others

Comment: thanks and sure no problem glad I could help it can be frustrating some times

Answer (score 0):

First declare a [FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) variable:

```
FragmentManager fm;
```

Then initialise it

```
fm = getFragmentManager();
```

then call it wherever you want..

```
createNewEdQua  dialogFragment = new createNewEdQua ();
dialogFragment.show(fm, "Your title");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your suggestion. But I still get an error. I delcared fm at the root level of the class. then initialised it in onCreateView(). then tried using it to call an instance of the DialogFragment. Got an error 'cant resolve method show'.

Comment: Instead of calling the Dialogfragment from the function addEdQua(), try to call it from the click function itself

Comment: I am now trying to call it from the onClick but I still get the same error. 'cant resolve method show'